# Why does this if statement of query return false?

Tags: php, mysqli

The problem I face is that the conditional sentence which i typed return false!

```
if ($db->addkey($key_value,$key_balance,$key_created_date))
{
    echo 'TRUE';
}
else
{

    echo 'FALSE';

}
```

I need to say the `$db->addkey($key_value,$key_balance,$key_created_date` worked and pass the values to database as perfect but i'm still wired why this statement return false?

The `addkey` function is:

```
    public function addkey($key_value,$key_balance,$key_created_date){
    if ( !$this->link ) return false;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `" . $this->table_prefix . "keys` (`key_value`,`key_balance`,
        `key_created_date`)
        VALUES('" . $this->realEscapeSingle($key_value) .
        "', '" . $this->realEscapeSingle((int)$key_balance) . "', '" . $this->realEscapeSingle($key_created_date) . "')";

    ++$this->queries_;
    mysqli_query($this->link,$query);

    $key_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->link);
    if( !$key_id )
    {
        echo mysqli_errno($this->link) . ": " . mysqli_error($this->link);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the Variables is:

```
$key_value = "25H8G-PIEAU-RB8H2";

$key_balance = 10;

$key_created_date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
```

Comment: Show us what the function  `->addkey` does

Comment: We don't know what addkey() does, and we don't know what error are you receiving (has your data any duplicated key that's forced to be unique at a database level?)

Comment: Also show us your MySQL Errors (if any) and your PHP error log notices (if any)

Comment: [J.Burke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9755112/j-burke) makes a good point that `Maybe it does not have a return value at all.` .... well, does it?

Comment: Sorry guys, i edit the post @Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you `addkey` method can never return *`true`*

Therefore when you test the method return in the `if(...)` statement, the if will never ever run, regardless of if the method performed its intended duty.

See the code:

```
public function addkey($key_value,$key_balance,$key_created_date){
    ....

  $key_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->link);
  if( !$key_id )
   {
     echo mysqli_errno($this->link) . ": " . mysqli_error($this->link);
     return false;
   }

 return true; // this catch that if none of the return false 
              // are triggered then the function MUST be true. 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add a `return true` somewhere in the `->addkey` method. Maybe at the bottom if no errors were detected?

Comment: I have +1 you as you (admittedly by chance) got the cause first!